# If $τ_n$ are stopping times with $τ_n\uparrow T$ and $X_n$ are random variable, then $\sum_n1_{\left\{τ_{n-1}<t\right\}}X_n$ is convergent

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-integrals, stopping-times

Let

- $T>0$
- $I:=(0,T]$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\in\overline I}$ be a filtration of $\mathcal A$
- $\tau_n:\Omega\to\overline I$ be an $\mathcal F$-stopping time with $$\tau_n\le\tau_{n+1}\tag1$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$ and $$\tau_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}T\tag2$$
- $X_n:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be $\mathcal F_{\tau_{n-1}}$-measurable for all $n\in\mathbb N$

> How can we show that $$\Phi_t:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}1_{\left\{\:\tau_{n-1}\:<\:t\:\right\}}X_n\;\;\;\text{for }t\in\overline I\tag3$$ is well-defined?

Let $(\omega,t)\in\Omega\times\overline I$. To be precise, I don't see why the series $\Phi_t(\omega)$ is convergent. If $t<T$, then $$\varepsilon:=T-t>0$$ and hence $$\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\tau_n(\omega)=T\tag4$$ by $(1)$ and $(2)$. Thus, $$t=T-\varepsilon=\tau_N(\omega)\le\tau_n(\omega)\;\;\;\text{for all }n\ge N\tag5$$ for some $N\in\mathbb N$ by definition of the supremum. Thus, $$\Phi_t(\omega)=\sum_{n=1}^N1_{\left\{\:\tau_{n-1}\:<\:t\:\right\}}(\omega)X_n(\omega)\tag6\;.$$ So, the only problematic case is $t=T$.

Comment: For every $t$, $$\Phi_t=\sum_{n=1}^{N(t)}X_n$$ where $$N(t)=\inf\{k\geqslant0\mid\tau_k\geqslant t\}$$ Thus, if $t<T$, $N(t)$ is almost surely finite hence the sum is well-defined because it involves a finite number of terms. But if $t=T$, it may happen that $N(t)=\infty$ and then $$\Phi_T=\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$$ may be undefined.

Comment: @Did Your $N(t)$ should agree with my $N$ (for the fixed $t$ I've chosen), at least if I choose $N$ to be minimal with the described property (which is of course possible). So, your $N(t)$ should be **surely** finite or did I miss something?

Comment: @Did What you say about $t=T$ is what I thought too. I've found this in *Foundations of Modern Probability* on [page 277](https://tinyurl.com/kgdxw59). The problem doesn't occur in the book, cause the considered time range doesn't contain its supremum. Can we fix the construction described there somehow?